# .wav sample data value starting index?

Tags: delphi, matlab, delphi-7, wav

I've been use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227719/read-wav-file-using-delphi) code to read .wav data in delphi and i've been comparing the result with value i got from matlab function wavread. From which i can say that matlab function can automatically recognize which one is the sample data value, but not with delphi (but both matlab and delphi code result is the same). Since my delphi code cannot recognize the sample data value, i look through the array and found out that the index where sample data value starting were different each .wav file. For an example i test some .wav file and get this:

1. classic1.wav the sample data value starting on wavedata[].Data[] index number 40
2. classic2.wav the sample data value starting on wavedata[].Data[] index number 35

i got above conclusion by looking at the result y,[y, Fs, nbits, opts]=wavread('classic1.wav','double'); then i go to the result delphi return in an array checking it value and find the exact same value starting in the index 40 for classic1.wav and 35 for classic2.wav. And i want to know if there is a way i can know the starting index of sample data value of each .wav file?

EDIT : i have corrected the record similar to the [reference](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) given, it's perfectly right with the header(from ChunkID to Subchunk2size)  but i still got confused by the sample data following it because no change from the previous result.

```
type
TWaveHeader = packed record

    Marker_RIFF: array [0..3] of char;
    ChunkSize: cardinal;
    Marker_WAVE: array [0..3] of char;


    Marker_fmt: array [0..3] of char;
    SubChunkSize: cardinal;
    FormatTag: word;
    NumChannels: word;
    SampleRate: longint;
    ByteRate: longint;
    BlockAlign:word; 
    BitsPerSample: word;


    Marker_data: array [0..3] of char;
    DataBytes: longint;
  end;

  TChannel = record
  Data : array of smallint;


end;
```

Comment: IIRC a simple WAVE file starts with a RIFF chunk descriptor, followed by a RIFF subheader, followed by a [WAVEFORMATEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. [I've actually written real WAVE encoders/decoders, but that was a few years ago, and I don't remember all the details. All I do know is that it is actually pretty easy.]

Comment: Andreas make a good point, you should revisit your struct declaration and split according [the specs](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)

Comment: yes i have reconstruct according the specs and it is right at least until the Subchunk2Size but not the data following it.i don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: A commercial library that does this for you and comes with source code is VC component set from lakesoft.  http://lakeofsoft.com/vc/download.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're obviously not skipping all of the header fields correctly. Wav files can have some optional header information, so though the actual sample values normally start at byte 44, this is not *always* the case.

See here for example: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

One way to skip directly to the sample data (after reading whatever parts of the header you require) is the scan the file (four bytes at a time) for the ascii string of "data" (64 61 74 61 hex) and then read the 4 bytes that immediately follow that, which (as cardinal or longword) represents the total number of *bytes* to read. The actual samples follow immediately after that cardinal.

Edit:

As expected, looking at the files Classic1.wav and Classic2.wav in a hex editor it's clear that they both have some metadata. At location 36 in each file, instead of finding the SubchunkID of "data" you instead find "LIST". The four bytes following this give the size of this additional data. This is what you have to skip over in order to get to the music sample data.

For example, Classic1.wav has 148 bytes of extra data starting at offset 44. This places Subchunk2ID at offset 192 and Subchunk2Size at offset 196, meaning that the first sample starts at offset 200 in the file.

Classic2.wav has 128 bytes of extra data starting at offset 44. This places Subchunk2ID at offset 172 and Subchunk2Size at offset 176, meaning that the first sample starts at offset 180 in the file.

Here is Classic2.wav in a very basic hex editor:
[image]

Comment: The number stored in the front of the `data` chunk is the **number of bytes** used by the sample data.  The **number of samples** is actually stored in a separate `fact` chunk instead. Remember that audio samples are not required to be, and usually are not, 8 bits in size.

Comment: @Stuart how do i do scan and looking "data" ?. Actually i'm just starting using delphi, maybe you can give me an example ?

Comment: @Remy. Yes you're right, it's the total number of *bytes*, not samples. I'll edit that to correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Wawan Upload and post a link to "classic1.wav" and "classic2.wav" so I can take a look in a hex editor.

Comment: @WawanMa-chun: rather than doing the file I/O manually, you should use the Win32 Multimedia API functions instead - [`mmioOpen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757331.aspx), [`mmioDescend()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757318.aspx), [`mmioAscend()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757315.aspx), [`mmioRead()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757334.aspx), etc. Let them do all of the hard work for you.

Comment: @Stuart here [Classic1](https://www.4shared.com/music/7F5FBC7r/classic1.html?) and [Classic2](https://www.4shared.com/music/7u6BfCAm/classic2.html?)

Comment: @Remy. oh i see there another way to do it? ok i'll learn it first. Thanks

Comment: @stuart i have downloaded a hex editor and looked at the offset 180 of classic2.wav is not the right start of the data. In fact at offset 180 it's value (4) in int 16 and (2.7813635e-309) in double where it should be either (-1) or (-3.051757812500000e-05). i've checked 10 data following after ofsset 180 and compared to the sequence matlab give me and it is not matched. OR maybe i'm far too confused to understand you T_T

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing all of the file I/O manually, you should use the Win32 Multimedia API functions instead - [mmioOpen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757331.aspx), [mmioDescend()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757318.aspx), [mmioAscend()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757315.aspx), [mmioRead()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757334.aspx), etc.  Let them do all of the hard work for you.  Your code will be easier to manage and read, as you will be able to focus more on the content of the individual chunks while letting the API handle the low-level details of finding each chunk for you.

Comment: The MSDN help says mmioOpen is deprecated?

Comment: I do not know why MSDN says that, considering that the other Multimedia functions are not deprecated, and `mmioOpen()` is the only way to open a file in a way that is compatible with them. `CreateFile()` is not a replacement for what `mmioOpen()` does. If you switch to `CreateFile()`, you have to handle all of the descending/ascending logic manually, which defeats the purpose of having a Multimedia API that does that for you.

Comment: MSDN, where the people who write the docs never think about things like this.